# Can I use an ajax GET request to a different portal?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, node.js, cross-domain

My front end is on the same domain as my server, call it X.  However, the front end is on port 8080, and the server (nodejs) is listening for activity on port 1337.  Whenever I got to X:1337 in my browser, I get the correct json displayed in my browser.  But when I try to use an ajax get request from the front end, the get request fails.  In firebug, it just shows the headers.  Is it a cross-domain issue? Or do different ports not matter?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a cross-origin issue. Use CORS, JSONP, or a server-side proxy. A request is cross-origin when any of the following parameters differ between the source and target origins: protocol, subdomain, domain, or port

Comment: Note that IE does not take into account port #s.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why this question has been downvoted, because this is actually an interesting issue, and one I had myself and worked out a solution to. Specifically, I like building my apps such that the front-end is a static site ([roots](http://roots.cx/)/[backbone](http://backbonejs.org/)/[marionette](http://marionettejs.com/) is a wonderful stack), and pulls data from a separate API app without cross-origin issues, and while keeping cookies intact so that I don't need to do token auth or anything. I'm not sure if you are up against a similar issue here, but it seems like you might be so here's how I solved it.

What I did is mapped both my servers onto a single domain name using [nginx](http://nginx.org/) (I wrote a [getting started guide here](http://carrot.is/coding/nginx_introduction)). This way, you have no cross-domain issues and they work together quite smoothly. You can use directive like the following to make this happen with nginx:

```
server {
  listen 1234;
  server_name localhost;

  # re-route all api requests and remove the
  # /api piece before routing them through
  location /api {
    rewrite ^(/api)(.*)$ /$2 break;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  }

  # pass through all other requests to the front end.
  # in production this should be compiled and use a regular
  # try_files block
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  }

}
```

With this code in place, you will have a server set up at `localhost:1234` that puts through all normal requests to your front-end running at `8080` and any request starting with `/api` to your node server at `1337`. In addition, since both are on the same domain, you won't have any cross-origin issues. This setup works nicely both locally and in production.